Quillen's theorem A/B for simplicially enriched categories
I'm looking for any reference which states some version of Quillen's theorem A/B for simplicially enriched categories (so to be clear, simplicial objects of $\mathrm{Cat}$ whose simplicial set of objects is constant).
Ideally, some theorem which gives conditions on a simplicial functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ between simplicially enriched categories which:
A. Guarantee the induced map on homotopy coherent nerves $F_*:N^{\mathrm{hc}}(\mathcal{C})\to N^{\mathrm{hc}}(\mathcal{D})$ is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories, or
B. Allows us to identify the homotopy fiber of $F_*:N^{\mathrm{hc}}(\mathcal{C})\to N^{\mathrm{hc}}(\mathcal{D})$ at an object $d\in N^{\mathrm{hc}}(\mathcal{D})$.

Joyal / Lurie showed that for a map $f : A \to B$ between quasi-categories, the conditions of Quillen’s theorem A say precisely that $f$ is a final functor of $\infty$-categories. These conditions are basically model-independent, so you should be able to read off a characterization of final functors of simplicially-enriched categories. But you seem to be asking for something different — some criterion analogous to Quillen’s theorem A which detects equivalences of $(\infty,1)$-categories. I don’t know of such a thing in any model

The usual Quillen theorems A/B concern properties of a functor of categories and deduce consequences about the corresponding map of nerves, regarded in the standard Quillen-Kan model structure (i.e. regarded as spaces). You seem to be asking instead about consequences of (homotopy coherent) nerves regarded as quasicategories/infty-categories. If that is the case, then there is a precise answer to A -  these F are the Dwyer-Kan equivalences. These are the weak equivalences in the Bergner model structure on simplicially enriched categories. (cont)

(cont) The homotopy coherent nerve is a right quillen equivalence between this model structure and the Joyal model structure on simplicial sets. So, you can use this to give some sort of answer to part B too. For example if F is a fibration in the Bergner model structure, then I think the homotopy fiber is just the nerve of the fiber. I am not sure if that is what you want.

Related to this, but in a different direction related to the second half of Tim's comment, is the paper, "QUILLEN THEOREMS Bn FOR HOMOTOPY PULLBACKS OF (∞,k)-CATEGORIES", by Barwick and Kan which discusses this issue in the model of relative categories among others.
